# Can we Delete the default Email Preference page in Pardot

Tags: pardot

How to delete the Default email preference page in Pardot

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete the default email preferences page but you can [create new ones](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pardot_emails_custom_preference_center_create.htm&type=0) and link to it in your emails in place of %%unsubscribe%% or %%email_preference_center%%